# Matplotlib: plotting sorted dates from strings

Tags: python, date, csv, matplotlib

I have to draw a graph having as x= date.append (c[1]) and the y=umidita.append (c[2]). I get this error, how do I? And also how I can put the dates in chronological order?
For example:
 I have in date.append: 28-10-2016 and 6-12-2016. In umidita.append: 86 and 78,9.
 centralina_min_distanza= Rome

```
dati = [("Rome", "6-12-2016", 78.9),
        ("Rome", "28-10-2016", 86),
        ("Milan", "6-12-2016", 155)] 

centralina_min_distanza= "Rome"
date=[]
umidita=[]
for c in dati:
    if c[0]==centralina_min_distanza:
        date.append(c[1]) #aggiungo dati e umidita alle liste
        umidita.append(c[2])


import numpy as np
import pylab
pylab.figure(1)
x=np.array([float(n) for n in c[1].split()])
y=np.array([float(n) for n in c[2].split()])
pylab.plot(x,y)
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Since we do not have access to your data, especially `dati`, it's pretty hard to see your problem. Please provide a [MCVE]. In order to do that, you may take the first few values of `dati` and put them into a hardcoded list. Also, assign a value for `centralina_min_distanza`.

Comment: Oh no! You made it worse, which words in [MCVE] did you not understand?

Comment: I edited the question to finally produce a [MCVE]. Please verify if this is indeed what you have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the exact scope is still unclear after a lot of modifications to the question and the problem is coompletely specific to the questioners needs. Since questioner is no longer on SO, there is no benefit on keeping this question alive.

Answer (score 0):

Means that `c[1].split()` and `c[2].split()` produce two lists of different length, you need to make sure that `len(c[1].split())` is the same as `len(c[2].split())`

Comment: Making sure `c[1].split()` and `c[2].split()` produce the same length lists eliminates the ValueError, but will most probably not produce the desired result. I think one should wait for a minimal example to see what is needed.

Comment: That's the whole thing I think (from the title), so if this resolves what is mentioned in the title then another question might be asked if any issue raises!

Comment: The user obviously wants a humidity vs. date graph and has problems producing it. If this question was solemnly about getting a ValueError (which I am not convinced of) it should be flagged as dublicate instead of being answered.